# Best approach to load data in Hive using Scala for multiple single record files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I have multiple files from source where each file contains single record details in  format. Eg.

```
Cust ID: 123,Cust name: XYZ, Some notes to be ignored, E-mail: XYZ@avdg.com
```

I have 10000 such files. I am reading each of these files individually through a loop in Scala code, extracting `fieldname` and `value` from each file and storing in a Spark `dataframe`. I am then making the necessary transformation in Spark `DF` and storing the `DF` in a `hive` table.
The problem is that the approach is taking too long to load data into Hive. The problem maybe because each file is being opened individually and getting processed. Is there any other way of speeding up the process?

Comment: what is the format of the file?. Is it like JSON key value pair..? Also, does all the file names end with same extension (like *.txt)?

Comment: cat *txt >> all_1000.txt and then hadoop fs -copyFromLocal all_1000.txt <hdfs_file> would work

Comment: They are mostly csv and txt files. The problem with concatenation of all files into a single files is that it's then difficult to parse the files as I would not know where each record data would start in a file. Currently since each file is a single record, I know what makes a record.

Comment: when you do "grep . file\*csv file\*txt", the result will append the filenames to the content. You can then redirect the results to a single file and then verify what goes wrong with each file.

Comment: Thanks for the input? Do you think there's anything I can do at the Hadoop/Hive config to increase number of readers. Not just in Hadoop but is there a way to increase number if readers through Scala. Or any config setting in any Hive or Spark xml file?

Comment: I'm not that good at configuring. usually the default parameter values work well. Avoid processing serial files within spark. Convert all your inputs to HDFS and give that as input to spark.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

1. Read all the required files and store into dataframe.
2. Merge/Union individual dataframes into single dataframe.
3. Repartition combined dataframe.
4. Store the repartitioned dataframe to Hive table.

Read all files and store into dataframes

```
val dfs = Seq('file1','file2').map { i =>
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(s"${'"'}$i${'"'})
}
```

Reduce  dataframes into one

```
val unionDF = dfs.reduceLeft((dfa, dfb) => 
  dfa.unionAll(dfb)
)
```

Repartition combined dataframe.

```
unionDF.coalesce(10)
```

Write to hive table

```
unionDF.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("database.table")
```

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing all of the data files in a single folder location and build an [external HIVE table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ManagedandExternalTables) on top of these files. Assuming it is a CSV file and all of your 10,000 files are having same structure, then building an external hive table would help you with your query.

In your external table; you can ignore the headers using the tblproperties as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <tableName>(
  col1 string,
  col2 int
  ....
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '<hdfs location of your files>'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

Well at this stage you will have a table with all of your dataset (unformatted). You can later create another table or views on top of your external table where you can format your data as per requirement. There are multiple functions in hive to achieve the desired output.

Hope this helps :)

*Note: This solution doesn't use spark.*